# How did Thor know the Power stone was in play?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron, guardians-of-the-galaxy

It's pretty obvious that Thor would know about the Tesseract, Aether and the Mind Stone, since he physically came into contact with all three and was instrumental in securing them. However, the Power stone came into play in a different part of the galaxy, during the events of Guardians of the Galaxy. During Thor's nightmare vision, he sees all four stones that are currently in play, and not all six total stones. With this in mind, it's like his vision is showing Thor information that he doesn't know, but that is currently correct according to what the audience know.

How did Thor know the Power stone was in play?

Comment: Uh, through said vision he got?

Comment: Yes but the visions are based on worst fears, why would Thor's nightmare indicates that the stone of power was in play and not... the other two? It seems far too specific and taking into consideration information that Thor doesn't know...

Comment: Well, the question is if it's a *vision* or a *nightmare*. In the former case there's no problem with the information being correct and being not known to him before. But I might agree that it's probably rather the latter.

Comment: Well, if we exclude Thor, it's obviously a nightmare/worst case scenario for everybody else, if we're including Thor and saying it's a vision, does that mean it's a vision for Captain America that he's back at the end of the war? Does that mean it's a vision for the Hulk to run off into the city?

Comment: Which is exactly why I tend to agree that it's rather a nightmare.

Comment: Hopefully my edit should clarify what I'm actually asking

Comment: Perhaps the events of Guardians took place right around the same time as Thor The Dark World and he heard about what went down on Xandar before he came back to earth.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

tl;dr: Assuming that he knew about the 4th Infinity Stone stone before his vision, he most likely learned about it sometime off-screen, between *Guardians of the Galaxy* and *Avengers: Age of Ultron*.

---

First of all, we can assume that Thor probably has fairly in-depth knowledge of the Infinity Stones, given that his friends do. This seems to be part of the normal education on Asgard: Sif not only calls them by name, but knows that Tesseract and Aether are both Stones *and* knows not to keep them all in one place.

Thus, when he saw the Infinity Stones in his vision, he would certainly have recognized them. However, as far as we know, his vision is merely a manifestation of his worst fears. While it makes sense, given the events of *Avengers* and *Thor 2*, that the Infinity Stones reemerging would have been his biggest fear. And, later on when he goes to the Waters of Sight, he would have learned everything everything else he needed, e.g. that it was the Mind Stone, and that Vision needed to exist. But the one thing he did see in his vision, that he shouldn't have know, was that there were **4** stones. How did he know to be afraid of four, not two (which he knew of) or three (if he suspected what the scepter was) or six (which is all of them)?

The clue is what he says at the end of the movie: that four of the stones have *appeared* in recent years. This implies that he knows of four specific cases where an Infinity Stone was active. On-screen, he's only encountered the Tesseract and Aether, and now the Mind Stone.  So, he must have learned about the events of *Guardians of the Galaxy* at some point off-screen.

Thor's a high-ranking Asgardian noble, he probably hears things. The destruction of Knowhere, the attack on Xandar, and the fact that an Infinity Stone was involved are all big newsworthy events. The Asgardians obviously have a working relationship with the Collector, and they have shown themselves to be well-versed in galactic history and lore, and willing to get involved in "peacekeeping" missions when needed.

The news of an Infinity Stone is exactly the kind of thing that would likely make its way to Asgard, either officially (maybe the Nova Corps has a diplomatic relationship with Asgard, we don't know), or via the rumor mill.

Comment: Also to take into factor the involvement of Thanos' daughters.

Comment: Also true; assuming Asgard knows who Thanos is, that would definitely raise the profile of those events and make it more likely that they'd pay attention.

Comment: Precisely... Thanos must've registered on Asgard's radar.

Answer (score -1):

It's like to add a different possibility.

Rather than the power stone, despite seeing it in the vision presented in the waters of sight. What if the fourth thst he knows has surfaced was the soul stone, which is housed in *Mjolnir*.

Something I think well be seeing as a result of Hela destroying it.
This could explain how Mjolnir is able to judge people worthy and animate itself, as well as why vision was able to lift it. Because of his connection with the mind stone.